# VS C++ 2010 debugging with external entry point

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, entry-point

I'm creating Win32 application and I have two projects.

The first one is a static library which contains _tWinMain() function, that is the entry point of a Win32 application.
The other one is an application which links this .lib. That way, the app doesn't have to create its own _tWinMain() function, because it's in the .lib file.

First, I build the static library. Then I build the application. The problem is that when I start debugging (F5), the window shows and then immediately closes (either in Debug or Release configuration). The problem doesn't occur when I start the program without debugging (Ctrl+F5) or just open the .exe file.
Is it possible to debug while having the entry point in a static library?

Comment: Wouldn't your dependencies be a little bit messed up?  How does _tWinMain() make calls into an application it doesn't know exists?

Comment: It is possible. _tWinMain() in lib only need a declaration of a function. And that function's definition can be done in the application.

Comment: The application works even without the declaration of _tWinMain() (without debugging of course), because the compiler doesn't look for the function declaration, it's the linker that looks for its definition. When debugging, the application quits whether_tWinMain() has been declared or not.

Comment: If you solved it, write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**
I had a small bug in one of my functions (always remember to initialize variables ;) ). _tWinMain() quited because of that. Now everything works fine, with the entry point in static library as described above. Thanks everyone for help and sorry for bothering you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible. Did you try what happens when you start the application with F11 or F10 instead of F5? It will then start the application, but breaks directly at WinMain.

Comment: When I start the application with F11 or F10 then it breaks at _tWinMain(). The source file from the first project which contains the implementation of _tWinMain() opens (notice this code hasn't been compiled in the app project, it had been already built into the linked .lib). But if I press F5 to continue,  the program terminates. Moreover, if I add any breakpoint in the source code of the application, it says: "The breakpoint won't be hit. No executable code is associated with this line". However, the breakpoints work in the source files of the lib project, for example inside _tWinMain().

Comment: That sounds to me like the build settings of the application might be incorrect. Check those and if you don't find anything strange set a breakpoint in the library source code right before code in the application project is being called. Hit F10/F11 until the debugger wants to step into the application project. Hopefully it will then give a useful warning or error.